# Read-Only Filesystem error when storing data on sdcard

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I'm developing an application with React Native. I want to store data on sdcard (external portable), specifically a Realm file. With help from RFNS, I'm able to get the path of what should be the directory of my app. However, when opening the file, it triggers "Read-Only Filesystem".

I already added the following permission on AndroidManifest.xml and before the execution, Android asks me whether my app can manage the storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then, this is my code which fails when opening Realm file:

```
let realmPath = `${RFNS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/default.realm`;    

Permissions.request('storage').then(response => {
              if (response === 'authorized') {
                RNFS.mkdir(realmDir).then(() => {
                  Realm.open({path: realmPath, schema: [CarSchema, PersonSchema]})
                  .then(realm => {
                    console.warn('opened')
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                  });
                });
              }
            }).catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
            })
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Writing to SD Card is a runtime permission since 6.0, adding "uses-permission" is insufficient

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Request external storage write permission in native (or find a library that does that)

Comment: already doing that with React Native Permissions...

Comment: @ian-ferreira Can you solve this?

Comment: moved on to Realm Java and created a bridge between RN and Android source code, @b24

Comment: Can you provide some sample about this?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but I have same issue in Android 5 too.